# rails naming convention - "Fuel"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions

I have a table called fuel that stores vehicle fuel data. Can anyone suggest the correct naming convention for the controller? Thanks

Comment: Sorry - and vehicle has_many :fuel(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally think that you can go ahead with 'Fuel', because for me making it plural seems odd.

Your table '`fuel`':

*So your model would be*

```
class Fuel < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "fuel"

  #your code 
end
```

*controller*

```
class FuelController < ApplicationController
  #controller code
end
```

*routes (config/routes.rb)*

```
resources :fuel #assuming you have a resource for this
```

Answer (score 1):

From the limited info you've given us, I'd think about it this way: it's data about fuel, not really units of fuel. I'd go with `FuelDatum`. Rails will pluralize that correctly, so you'll have a table and routes named `fuel_data`.

OTOH, we might be able to come up with something cleaner if you tell us more about what fields are in there. For example, why does a car have many of them? Like, what do the represent, exactly? The more explicit you are, the easier it is to turn into a good name.

Comment: +1 @jared should probably go with `FuelUnit` or `FuelAmount` for the model name, and have a capitalized controller name, viz: `fuel_units_controller` or `fuel_amounts_controller`.

Comment: The purpose of the model is to store fuel records for vehicles. The schema is: `  create_table "fuel", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.datetime "fuel_date"
    t.integer  "vehicle_id"
    t.integer  "mileage"
    t.integer  "hours"
    t.decimal  "cost",                      :precision => 8, :scale => 4
    t.decimal  "tax",                       :precision => 8, :scale => 4
    t.decimal  "litres",                    :precision => 8, :scale => 2
    t.integer  "repairer_id"
    t.string   "fuel_type",   :limit => 45
  end`